# how to connect to an already running roscore from a tethered usb device

Tags: ros, linux, ubuntu, network, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

i am trying to connect to an already running roscore with a tethered usb device.

situation is as follows:

1. i have a running roscore on a
   ubuntu machine
2. **after** the
   roscore is up, i connect an android
   tablet to the computer and create a
   network connection using usb
   tethering
3. i am using ros android
   to communicate with the roscore

note:

- connecting the tablet with usb tethering creates a new usb network device over which i want to talk to the roscore
- the tablet may be connected and disconnected several times without re-starting the roscore
- also maybe other clients connect to the master using a ethernet connection

has anyone an idea how to do that ?  how would the ros network setup look like (master uri / ros ip / ros hostname) ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46321/how-to-connect-to-an-already-running-roscore-from-a-tethered-usb-device/) by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like i found a working solution myself.
this also works if you have the following setup:
running roscore on a machine A
connect ethernet cable and get ip adress via dhcp
communicate from a machine B via network to roscore on machine A

the solution is to set up a network bridge on machine A which bridges to all other network devices (e.g usb0, eth0 ...). Assign a static IP to the bridge device and set ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_IP to that ip. Start the roscore.
When plugin the ethernet cable or tablet (...) just restart the bridge adapter using ifconfig down/up and all devices can communicate with the core using the bridge adapter's ip

---

Originally posted by [jochen.mueck](https://answers.ros.org/users/3089/jochen.mueck/) with karma: 48 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1